# SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG with custom server

Tags: java, ssl

I've created a [web server](https://gitlab.com/bullbytes/simple_socket_based_server) based on sockets. It can serve files via HTTPS or HTTP.

The issue I'm experiencing occurs when requesting a file, such as an image, from the server via HTTPS using Firefox and Chromium.

When Firefox requests the image from the server at `https://localhost:8443/ada.jpg`, Firefox reports

> SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

Similarly, Chromium errors with

> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

The following works fine though:

- cURL getting the image via HTTPS: `curl -Ok "https://localhost:8443/ada.jpg"`
- Getting a text response via HTTPS using cURL, Firefox, and Chromium: `https://localhost:8443/`
- Getting a smaller image (6773 bytes) like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aM1yy.jpg) via HTTPS using cURL, Firefox, and Chromium
- Getting the image via HTTP (no TLS) using cURL, Firefox, and Chromium: `http://localhost:8443/ada.jpg`

I've used Wireshark to look at the frames while the browsers are getting the image: Both Firefox and Chromium send a `[FIN, ACK]` frame to the server while the image is still being transmitted. The server continues sending parts of the image after which the browsers send a `[RST]` frame.

These are the last couple of frames from the exchange between Firefox and the server:

```
25  1.873102771 ::1 ::1 TCP 86  55444 → 8443 [ACK] Seq=937 Ack=18043 Win=56704 Len=0 TSval=3976879013 TSecr=3976879013
26  1.873237965 ::1 ::1 TLSv1.3 110 Application Data
27  1.873247272 ::1 ::1 TCP 86  8443 → 55444 [ACK] Seq=18043 Ack=961 Win=65536 Len=0 TSval=3976879013 TSecr=3976879013
28  1.873346910 ::1 ::1 TCP 86  55444 → 8443 [FIN, ACK] Seq=961 Ack=18043 Win=65536 Len=0 TSval=3976879013 TSecr=3976879013
29  1.876736432 ::1 ::1 TLSv1.3 16508   Application Data
30  1.876769660 ::1 ::1 TCP 74  55444 → 8443 [RST] Seq=962 Win=0 Len=0
```

[Here](https://gitlab.com/bullbytes/simple_socket_based_server/tree/9933d074901cb11dfcc2f356abf904c41e108234/wireshark) are the Wireshark captures of cURL and Firefox.

---

For reproducing the error, do

```
git clone git@gitlab.com:bullbytes/simple_socket_based_server.git
cd simple_socket_based_server
./gradlew run
```

This starts the server with TLS enabled. Then, open the following URL in your browser (the first time you'll have to add an exception for the self-signed certificate):

```
https://localhost:8443/ada.jpg
```

To convince yourself that transferring the image succeeds when TLS is disabled, start the server like this:

```
./gradlew run --args="--use-tls=no"
```

After removing the `s` from the protocol, the image should show up in your browser:

```
http://localhost:8443/ada.jpg
```

The server's request-handling loop is [here](https://gitlab.com/bullbytes/simple_socket_based_server/blob/master/src/main/java/com/bullbytes/simpleserver/Start.java#L70).

How can I debug this further and fix it?

---

I'm on Arch Linux 5.2.9 using OpenJDK 12.0.2+10.

Comment: Did you already check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119336/ssl-error-rx-record-too-long-and-apache-ssl ?

Comment: Yes I did. The issue described in that question is a misconfiguration of Apache and doesn't fit the symptoms described in my question where transferring data via TLS works under some conditions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## This is a bug in the JDK

It was fixed¹ in JDK 13.

The original bug report is [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8221253) with the title

> TLSv1.3 may generate TLSInnerPlainText longer than 2^14+1 bytes

which is consistent with the observations in the question: A record longer than that [violates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#section-6.2) the TLSv1.3 protocol.

[This bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8225714) states that Java's TLS implementation is fixed in JDKs 11.0.5 b01 and 13 via [this commit](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk-updates/jdk11u/rev/112bea49c0fa).

Generally, [JDK 13 reimplemented](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/353) `Socket` and `ServerSocket`², making them play well with fibers introduced in [project Loom](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main).

The bug I filed for JDK 12 is [here](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-8230788).

### Workaround

If upgrading the JDK is not possible in your situation, you could use [`ServerSocketChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/channels/ServerSocketChannel.html) instead of `ServerSocket` for now. [Jetty](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/e117fbe8281bd43ec5601a30d39f50a09cbcef22/jetty-server/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ServerConnector.java#L322) does that.

---

¹<sub>The bug does not occur with OpenJDK build 13+33 on Arch Linux: The image shows up fine in Firefox</sub>

²<sub>[The server](https://gitlab.com/bullbytes/simple_socket_based_server) used to reproduce the error is built on `ServerSocket`.</sub>